# Python Connection to Oracle DB: cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, connection, client, path-variables

I am currently trying to get a connection to a remote Oracle Database using cx_Oracle.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cx_Oracle

#create connection
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("User", "Password", "DBHost", 
encoding="UTF-8")
print('It Works!')
```

When i try to connect to the Database i get this message:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library
```

What I tried after this Message:

1. Downloading and Installing the Oracle Client

   - Still the same Message
2. Then I added the Path Variable of the installed Client

   - Still the same Message

Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: How did you set the path variable of the installed client? I think this might be the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the PATH is exported? Can strace tell you something more? $strace myapp.py

Comment: I did it like this: export PATH=$PATH:/home/dtv/Installfiles/InstantClientOracle/instantclient_19_9

I am pretty new to this kind of thinks so..

I unziped the zip file from the oracle client and made a path from that directory

Comment: /home/dtv/Installfiles/InstantClientOracle/instantclient_19_9/bin ?

Comment: there is no  'bin' inside that directory..

Comment: @Sejachu Did you follow the instructions (at the bottom of the looong page, Installation of ZIP files)? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html Did you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you are on Linux.

The cx_Oracle installation instructions for using Oracle Instant Client on Linux are [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#oracle-instant-client-zip-files).

Try running ldconfig or setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH as shown in the instructions.

```
sudo sh -c "echo home/dtv/Installfiles/InstantClientOracle/instantclient_19_9 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```